# set systemProperty in exec-maven-plugin does not work

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>my_proj</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>

                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath />
                                <argument>com.test.Main</argument>

                            </arguments>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <systemProperty>
                                    <key>someKey</key>
                                    <value>someValue</value>
                                </systemProperty>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <someKey>
                                    someValue
                                </someKey>
                            </environmentVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

and in Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("hello world" + System.getenv("someKey") + " " + System.getProperty("someKey"));
}
```

the output when I run

```
mvn install -Pmy_proj
```

is

```
hello worldsomeValue null
```

I cannot seem to get the systemProperty value. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `systemProperty` does not work simply because it is not an expected element of the [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal of the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Check the official [`exec` goal page](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), no `systemProperties` element is specified. As such, your configuration is still valid for Maven simply because is well-formed XML, but it is ignored by the `exec-maven-plugin`.

From official [Maven Pom Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) concerning the plugin `configuration` element:

> It may be good to note that all configuration elements, wherever they are within the POM, are intended to pass values to another underlying system, such as a plugin. In other words: values within a configuration element are never explicitly required by the POM schema, but a plugin goal has every right to require configuration values.

---

You are making confusion with the [`systemProperties`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#systemProperties) configuration entry foreseen by its [`java`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal. This option is available there because of its context: it's crafted for java executions. On the other hand, the `exec` goal is much more generic and as such cannot foresee an option required only by java programs.

To pass system properties to a Java execution via the `exec` goal, you can use the [`arguments`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#arguments) configuration entry and use the [`-D` notation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> `-Dproperty=value`       Sets a system property value.

Further note, as per official [Running Java programs with the exec goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) documentation, the `-D` arguments should go first:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-DsomeKey2=someValue2</argument>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath />
        <argument>com.test.Main</argument>
    </arguments>
    <environmentVariables>
        <someKey>someValue</someKey>
    </environmentVariables>
</configuration>
```

Moreover, you should not set the same variable name for environment and as system property, the system property would not be set otherwise.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I edited the comment and mark your answer as correct